# APC Memory Pool and Apache Problems

Tags: apache-2.2, php, http, alternative-php-cache

i have a problem with my APC and Apache.
Since i have been installed APC on my VPS, i face to many problems. Here is one of them.

My Apache keeps falling down, server port :80 is available, but its giving me error message.

My Configuration:
/etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini

```
extension=apc.so
apc.shm_size=30
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.write_lock = 1
apc.rfc1867 = On
apc.ttl=7200
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.num_files_hint=1024
apc.mmap_file_mask=/dev/zero
apc.enable_cli=1
```

Error in Apache Log:

```
    [Tue Mar  4 13:49:42 2014] [apc-error] apc_mmap: mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory
    [Tue Mar  4 13:49:47 2014] [apc-error] apc_mmap: mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory
    [Tue Mar  4 13:49:47 2014] [apc-error] apc_mmap: mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory
    [Tue Mar  4 13:48:39 2014] [apc-warning] Unable to allocate memory for pool. in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/xxx/application/libraries/Engine/Loader.php on line 103.
```

I dont know why i have this problems, when in my APC.ini i have apc.shm_size defined.

Comment: Please provide more info about your system. Free RAM, PHP & apc version etc.
Maybe you just ran out of memory or if your apc version is above If your version is 3.1.5 you might have to add a M to apc.shm_size

Answer (score 0):

```
-> PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze18
-> APC Version  3.1.3p1
->      total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:     4096       2699       1396          0          0     1205
```

My Apache Error Log is clean now after i setup apc.ini as this:
extension=apc.so
apc.shm_size=96
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.write_lock = 1
apc.rfc1867 = On
apc.ttl=3600
apc.user_ttl=3600
apc.gc_ttl=3600
apc.num_files_hint=1024
apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.enable_cli=1

I think the trouble makes apc.mmap_file_mask and shm_size is incrased without problem.
Now my apache is clean.